# why i get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values from nginx

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx

i get the following message in my browser:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myApidomain.de' from origin 'myorigindomain.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'myorigindomain.de, myorigindomain.de', but only one is allowed.`

The message is clear. But it wasnt clear if you take a look at my nginx default.conf:

```
server {

  listen 8000 default_server;
  listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/html/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT' always;
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, v-access-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  
  location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
   
      #fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
      fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
      #fixes timeouts
      fastcgi_send_timeout 6000;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
      include fastcgi_params;
      internal;
           
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH, PUT' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,v-access-header,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
          #add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
          #add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
          #return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)") {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT' always;
          add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, v-access-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      }
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
      log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

there is only 1 Header allow origin... why i get multiple? is there a way to find out where the second entry is coming from?
When i delete this entry my GET request dont work because "NO ALLOW-ORIGIN Header is present."
Now the GET is working and the POST make this error.

Comment: base in the configuration of nginx looks like more an config err, but do you if you are using like nemio-cors-bundle or other tool to manage the CORS?

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. Thank you. I have additional config with nelmio. Fixed it now. perfect.